# `initialize': undefined method `dirpathname=' for CheckDir:Class (NoMethod Error)

Tags: ruby, class-method

I am a new ruby guy and I tried to make a small program, but something is bugging me that I can't find solution. Please advise me. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

there would be 3 files. main.rb, create.rb and check.rb

when I run this problem I got an error like this;

`initialize': undefined method`dirpathname=' for CheckDir:Class (NoMethodError)

[main.rb]

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

BASE_DIR = File.join('','home','local','tester','code','www','test')
APP_ROOT = File.dirname(__FILE__)

$:.unshift(File.join(APP_ROOT, 'lib'))

require 'create'

THEME_DIR = ARGV[0]

if !THEME_DIR
  puts "Usage: ruby #{__FILE__} <the name of theme directory>\n\n"
  exit!
end

sym = CreateSymlink.new(THEME_DIR)
sym.launch!
```

[create.rb]

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'check'

class CreateSymlink
  def initialize(path=nil)
    CheckDir.dirpathname = BASE_DIR + "/" + path
    if CheckDir.dir_exists?
      puts "The #{path} is already existed! Bye."
      exit!
    end
  end

  def launch!
    puts "yeah"
    #lets_start(path)
  end
end
```

[check.rb]

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class CheckDir
  @@dirpathname = nil
  def self.dirpathname(path=nil)
    @@dirpathname = File.join(BASE_DIR, path)
  end

  def self.dir_exists?
    if @@dirpathname && File.directory?(@@dirpathname)
      return true
    else
      return false
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for the method called `dirpathname=` (which does not exist) instead of `dirpathname` (which does exist).

Either rename the method (by adding the "=") to use the "setter magic" or invoke the method as it is with `dirpathname(value)`

---

It helps to read the error message with emphasis ..

> undefined method **dirpathname=** for CheckDir:Class (NoMethodError)

.. note that the **=** *is* part of the message ("method") name and see [this tutorial on Ruby syntax sugar](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_syntactic_sugar.html).

In Ruby syntax `obj.method = value` is sugar for `obj.method=(value)` which in turn is sugar for `obj.__send__(#method=, value)`. That is, the message "method=" is sent to "obj" with "value" as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I am not sure what you mean because there is no such 'dirpathname=' in my code so I don't understand the error message

Comment: Ahh, yeah I just noticed that self.dirpathname(path=nil) has problem. It should be like self.dirpathname=(path=nil). Thanks much

Comment: @user1628920: Yes, that's exactly the problem. There is no `dirpathname=` method in your code, but you are calling it on line 6 of `create.rb` (the first line of `CreateSymlink#initialize`).